# What is the series expansion of this polynomial to the negative power?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$$
\left(\,
1 + x + {1 \over 2}\,x^{2} + {5 \over 18}\,x^{3} + {25 \over 144}\,x^{4}
\,\right)^{-2}
$$

How would I go about finding the series expansion of this ?.

I know how to use the Taylor expansion, but not how the negative power would affect the answer.

Comment: About what point do you want to expand this?

Comment: Oh sorry, at x =0.

Comment: There is nothing special about the negative power. Taylor expansion will work, just apply the formula. (Alternatively, use long polynomial division.)

Comment: See [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: At this point, I don't see any shortcuts. If you only have to do the first few terms, using the formula $c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ should work.

Comment: I've got it now, thanks for the help. The negative power made me think it would work differently.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series for $f$ about $x=0$ is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n \quad\text{ where }\quad c_n={f^{(n)}(0)\over n!},
$$
which in this case for your $f(x)$ above yields 
$$
1-2x+2x^2-{14\over 9}x^3+{77\over 72}x^4-{11x^5\over 24}+\cdots
$$